# как изменить тип данных числа в Python

Tags: python

Тип числа 1/3 - это 'float'.
Как перевести число из одного типа в другой (float16, float32, float64)?

Comment: Перевод выполнится автоматически интерпретатором

Comment: А зачем вам это?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1/3], dtype=np.float64)
b = a.astype(np.float32)
c = a.astype(np.float16)

print(type(a[0]))
print(type(b[0]))
print(type(c[0]))
```

Comment: Вообще-то ответ относиться к numpy, что несколько отличается от вопроса ТС,  который  может трактоваться, как тип данных числа в (чистом) Python.

Comment: хочу чтобы все числа были например только float32. Как узнать какого типа данное число?

Comment: @bluesky для обычных переменных вы не можете это контролировать. Конкретный тип всегда будет такой, какой "решит" использовать интерпретатор (разный в зависимости от системы). Для хранения "блоков" данных можно использовать array, там можно задать тип элемента, см.: [docs.python.org/3/library/array.html](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html) Ну или тот же numpy использовать.

Comment: @passant Так в чистом питоне и нет такого разделения, там вроде просто `float` без оттенков.

Comment: @CrazyElf так и я о том-же. Вопрос - про чистый Python, где это сделать невозможно. Ответ -  по numpy, где это сделать можно.

Comment: "Оттенки" чисел в чистом питоне есть: https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html

Answer (score 0):

Если мы говорим о `numpy`, то просто через `np.<necessary_dtype>()`:

```py
num = 44.64979415130181
num16 = np.float16(num) #44.66
num32 = np.float32(num) #44.649796
num64 = np.float64(num) #44.64979415130181
```